# Why is $5(3^k - 2^k) - 6(3^{k-1} - 2^{k-1}) = (5 \times 3 - 6)3^{k-1} - (5 \times 2 - 6)2^{k-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying for an upcoming exam by doing practice problems, and this simplification was used in one of the solutions. However, I do not understand why or how these two terms are equal.

EDIT: had the wrong equation in the title at first; fixed now.

Comment: Hint: $3^k=3\cdot 3^{k-1}$ and $2^k=2\cdot 2^{k-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{align}5(3^k - 2^k) - 6(3^{k-1} - 2^{k-1}) &= 5 \times 3^k - 6\times 3^{k-1} - 5 \times 2^k +6\times 2^{k-1}\\ &=3^{k-1}(5\times 3-6)-2^{k-1}(5\times 2-6)
\end{align}$

In the first line, I am just grouping the like powers together(powers of $3$ with powers of $3$, and powers of $2$ with powers of $2$), as demanded in the RHS of the equality. Have you understood?

Comment: We can view this as making explicit the algebraic relations among the exponentials - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Key Idea** $ $  Make *explicit* the *algebraic dependencies* among the exponentials by choosing a minimal generating set, here $\,x = 3^{\large k-1},\, y = 2^{\large k-1}\,$ so $\,3^{\large k} = 3x,\, 2^{\large k} = 2y\,$  and now it is obvious, viz.

$$\color{#c00}5(\color{#c00}3x-2y) \color{#c00}{- 6}(x-y)\, =\, (\color{#c00}{5\times 3-6})x - (5\times 2 - 6) y$$

**Remark** $ $ The same idea works generally, i.e. once we make the algebraic dependencies *explicit* then it reduces to trivial polynomial arithmetic. These ideas are made more precise when one studies (function) field theory in abstract algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Equality holds because $5\times3^k=5\times3\times3^{k-1}$ and $5\times2^k=5\times2\times2^{k-1}$

(using the hint from [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)).

You can cancel $6(3^{k-1}-2^{k-1})$ from both sides.